# for Loop with multiplication option not working in python

Tags: python

I have a following python code which does not seem to be looping:

```
area = 2000
for i in range(0-10):
       area = area + (6*i)
       print area
```

What is wrong with the above loop as it does not iterate?

Answer (score 2):

`range(0-10)` is the same as `range(-10)` which is `[]` on python2.x.  I'm guessing you want:

```
range(0, 10)
```

which will give you the numbers 0 through 9 (inclusive).  Note that this is the same as `range(10)` -- when the first argument is omitted, it defaults to `0`.

Answer (score 0):

This line is not correct

```
for i in range(0-10)
```

This actually produces

```
for i in range(-10) # because it is subtracting `10` from `0`
```

You want

```
for i in range(10)
```

Which produces a list of numbers from 0 to 9.